# Linq to XML Questions: Why is my query not working

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

At the point of my issue i have the following XML in an XElement. There can be many of these "Identifiers" nodes in the full XML and my navigation is working to this point.

```
    <Identifiers>
      <identifier>
        <Type>MR</Type>
        <Value>123321</Value>
        <Authority></Authority>
      </identifier>
      <identifier>
        <Type>AN</Type>
        <Value>123321-01</Value>
        <Authority></Authority>
      </identifier>
      <identifier>
        <Type>PN</Type>
        <Value>123321</Value>
        <Authority></Authority>
      </identifier>
    </Identifiers>
```

Here the is the Linq-To-XML:

```
    id = xd.Root.Element("Patient");
    id = id.Element("Identifiers"); //At this point "id" contains the above XML.
    id = id.Elements("Identifier").FirstOrDefault(x => x.Element("Type").Value == "AN");
```

Is the last statement where it falls apart and is returning null.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since XML is case sensitive, trying replacing "Identifier" in your last statement with "identifier".

Comment: Thank you much for the assistants I totally over looked that, guess I was just to intent on the linq syntax. Boy do I feel dumb.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `xd` is your XDocument, then try this:

```
xd.Descendents("identifier").FirstOrDefault(x => x.Element("Type").Value == "AN");
```

In fact, if you only expect a single "AN" value for type in your document, then you can do this:

```
 xd.Descendents("Type").FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value.Equals("AN"));
```

Or if you possibly have many "Type" with value "AN":

```
xd.Descendents("Type").Where(x => x.Value.Equals("AN"));
```